# Issues installing yhat on Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, input, output, preprocessor, rodeo

I just got access to use a ScienceOps server at my work and pip installed the yhat module. The first issue with the installation was that the poster dependency was not compatible with Python 3.x, so I installed: https://github.com/mrd1no/poster-0.8.1-for-Python-3.4

Yhat then correctly installed as a result. However, now when I try to run the Hello World example, I am running into the issue of:

`ImportError: No module named 'input_and_output'`

This comes from the model.py file where:

`from input_and_output import df_to_df, parse_json, preprocess`

I did some searching and couldn't find any evidence of this module, does that module only exist in Python 2.x?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

EDIT:

It looks like input_and_output is a python file under a sub-directory of yhat. However, the models.py still can't find the input_and_output file

Answer (score 0):

yhat isn't compatible with Python 3.x, it is reccomended to work with python 2.7.x